# Cannot proxy request from 'localhost:3000' to 'http://localhost:5000' ECONNREFUSED?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, proxy

I realise this question has been asked and answered many times before. None of the answers seem to work though?

I've basically forked an ecommerce project, for learning purposes, from github and trying to get it to work on my machine. My frontend is trying to connect to a MongoDB database being served at "http://localhost:5000/"...

Here I think is the code where it's going wrong  (in server.js)...

```
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URL || "mongodb://localhost/react-shopping-cart-db",
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
);
```

I've ran into similar trouble before trying to get React Apps that need to communicate with a database to work properly. I've implemented a Full Stack before in Django (Python) and got database to run fine. Am I supposed to instantiate the database and run any database migrations or the like from my command line before running the app?

I have looked up this question on here and tried all the suggestions therein... putting an extra / after the 5000... various proxy settings (127.0.0.1:5000) and so on with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Gavin.

Comment: Just to clarify: your frontend running on 3000 port, the database on 5000 and you trying to connect the frontend (the browser) to the database directly? How do you do this? You need the backend running on some port, which you should call, and the backend should call the database

Comment: Yes. Database is running on 5000 via 'server.js' in root of project and the app is running on 3000. I will be honest and say that I've forked somebody else's project and just trying to get it to work on my own machine for study purposes. I've tried running 'npm run server' and 'npm start' at the same time. I have also tried variations on fiddling with the "proxy" setting in 'package.json'. I tried lots of things as per suggested on similar Stack Overflow q&a posts. I'm assuming everything is as it should be in repo I forked from.

Comment: As I understand it, the project itself has taken care of all the database stuff and I don't need to create it myself or run any migrations or the like from the command line. I think the problem is to do with my proxy setting but don't know how to put it right. Here it is in my 'package.json' -  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"  -  having the "/" or not at the end hasn't made a difference.